# Calculating expression by converting infix into postfix gives false output when number greater than 9

Tags: java

Here `ch_st` is my character stack and `dbl_st` is my double stack

```
class conversion_and_solution{
    public static String postfix = "";//taken a string for the output

    public boolean isOperand(char c){//checks weather it is operand or not
        if(c>='0'&&c<='9')
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public boolean isOperator(char c){//checks weather operator
        if(c=='+'||c=='*'||c=='/'||c=='-')
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public int Opweight(char op){//checks Operator weight
        int op_wt = 0;
        switch(op){
            case '+':{
                op_wt = 1;
                break;
            }
            case '-':{
                op_wt = 1;
                break;
            }
            case '/':{
                op_wt = 2;
                break;
            }
            case '*':{
                op_wt = 2;
                break;
            }
            default:{
                System.out.println("Not Operator");
                break;
            }
        }
        return op_wt;
    }
    public boolean HigherPrecedence(char op1,char op2){//checks the precedence
        int p_op1 = Opweight(op1);
        int p_op2 = Opweight(op2);
        if(p_op1>p_op2)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    public String convert_to_postfix(String expression){//this is for converting infix to postfix
        char []chr = new char[expression.length()];
        char_stack ch_st = new char_stack();//object of character stack
        String ss = " ";
        for(int i=0;i<expression.length();i++){
            chr[i] = expression.charAt(i);
            //Now simple condition for checking weather Operand , Operator etc and doing the job
            if(isOperator(chr[i])){
                while(!ch_st.isEmpty()&&ch_st.char_top()!='('&&HigherPrecedence(ch_st.char_top(),chr[i])){
                    postfix= postfix+ch_st.char_top();
                    ch_st.char_pop();
                }
                ch_st.char_push(chr[i]);
            }
            else if(isOperand(chr[i])){
                postfix = postfix + chr[i];
            }

            else if(chr[i]=='('){
                ch_st.char_push(chr[i]);
            }
            else if(chr[i]==')'){
                while(!ch_st.isEmpty()&&ch_st.char_top()!='('){
                    postfix = postfix + ch_st.char_top();
                    ch_st.char_pop();
                }
                ch_st.char_pop();
            }
        }
        while(!ch_st.isEmpty()){//till not empty will pop the value and make the stack empty giving the output
            postfix = postfix + ch_st.char_top();
            ch_st.char_pop();
        }
        return postfix;
    }
    public double solve_eqns(){
        char []ch = new char[postfix.length()];
        double_stack dbl_st = new double_stack();
        double result;
        for(int i=0;i<postfix.length();i++){
            ch[i] = postfix.charAt(i);
            if(isOperand(ch[i])){//Checks for Operand
                double x = Character.getNumericValue(ch[i]);
                dbl_st.dbl_push(x);
                dbl_st.dbl_display();
            }
            //Now if tey are operators the task is performed
            if(isOperator(ch[i])){
                if(ch[i]=='/'){
                    double d1 = dbl_st.dbl_top();
                    dbl_st.dbl_pop();
                    double d2 = dbl_st.dbl_top();
                    dbl_st.dbl_pop();
                    double temp = d2/d1;
                    dbl_st.dbl_push(temp);
                }
                else if(ch[i]=='*'){
                    System.out.println("\n\nOperation to be done:*");
                    double d1 = dbl_st.dbl_top();
                    dbl_st.dbl_pop();
                    double d2 = dbl_st.dbl_top();
                    dbl_st.dbl_pop();
                    double temp = d2*d1;
                    dbl_st.dbl_push(temp);
                }
                else if(ch[i]=='+'){
                    System.out.println("\n\nOperation to be done:+");
                    double d1 = dbl_st.dbl_top();
                    dbl_st.dbl_pop();
                    double d2 = dbl_st.dbl_top();
                    dbl_st.dbl_pop();
                    double temp = d2+d1;
                    dbl_st.dbl_push(temp);
                }
                else if(ch[i]=='-'){
                    System.out.println("\n\nOperation to be done:-");
                    double d1 = dbl_st.dbl_top();
                    dbl_st.dbl_pop();
                    double d2 = dbl_st.dbl_top();
                    dbl_st.dbl_pop();
                    double temp = d2-d1;
                    dbl_st.dbl_push(temp);
                }
            }
        }
        result = dbl_st.dbl_top();
        dbl_st.dbl_pop();
        dbl_st.dbl_display();
        System.out.println("\nOutput:"+result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Here I am trying to solve an Infix Equation and I am getting false output as my code is considering every operator or operand as a character...

For example

1. If expression is (7+9)*4-12  gives correct output 52.
2. But if expression is (17+2)*4 then error occurs... it takes 7 and 1 as different numbers hence false output

So I want to know what changes in the code can make the inputs greater than 10 work properly

Here I am also not able to deal with unary operators

Comment: And the question is ??

Comment: Just edited the question I want a little help in my code which can allow user to enter values greater than 9

Comment: So you are writing your own expression parser that parses everything one character at a time. Most expression parsers will start by tokenizing the expression, such that `sqrt(17 + 5 * 6)` becomes `sqrt`, `(`, `17`, `+`, `5`, `*`, `6`, `)`. Spaces have been eliminated and multi-character "elements" are  a single token. Then you interpret the tokens, e.g. by realizing that the token with letters `1` and `7` is actually the numeric literal for the decimal number `17` (hex 11, binary 10001).

Comment: I think the question is pretty misleading. It's really not got anything to do with infix and postfix operators. The question is really how to cope with multi-digit operands.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to revise your logic to take a more traditional approach of splitting [lexical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) and semantic analysis. This will make your code more straightforward and easier to maintain than going directly from characters to interpretation.

However if you need to stick to your current approach then there is a relatively easy answer. In the code that processes operands you can continue to process numeric characters and add them as digits:

```
if (isOperand(ch[i])){
    double x = Character.getNumericValue(ch[i]);
    while (i < postFix.length() && isOperand(ch[i+1])) {
        x = 10 * x + Character.getNumericValue(ch[++i]);
    }
    dbl_st.dbl_push(x);
    dbl_st.dbl_display();
}
```

Though, as mentioned above, I would not recommend this approach. Much better is to convert to tokens before attempting to analyse semantics.